# Memory leak in OpenSSL function EVP_PKEY_keygen

Tags: c, memory-leaks, openssl

I just tried to generate a RSA key using:

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>

int main(void) {
  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

  EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx;
  EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;

  ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_RSA, NULL);
  if (!ctx) {
      // error
  }

  if (EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(ctx) <= 0) {
      // error
  }

  if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_keygen_bits(ctx, 2048) <= 0) {
      // error
  }

  if (EVP_PKEY_keygen(ctx, &pkey) <= 0) { // this call seems to leak
      // error
  }

  EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
  EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);

  EVP_cleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

So far, I don't think that I'm doing anything wrong.
Valgrind complains "in use at exit: 416 bytes in 6 blocks".
First I thought, I forgot something to free, afterwards I tried

> valgrind openssl genrsa 1024

And I also got "in use at exit: 416 bytes in 6 blocks".
Hum?! Even OpenSSL's official binary leaks?

[Openssl's FAQ](https://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#PROG13) tells:

> "Brutal" (thread-unsafe) Application-global cleanup functions:
>
> ERR_free_strings(), EVP_cleanup() and CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data().

If I execute *CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data()* it does not leak. But according to the OpenSSL documentation it is a "brutal" method, whatever that means. There is no further documentation on this function.

Is there any way to clean it up properly?

I'm using OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

Comment: There was a HUGE SECURITY PROBLEM with OpenSSL when a developer decided to cleanup the "leaks". Some of these are intended to be there, to get some entropy to the key.

Comment: Any references on that issue?

Comment: Yep. I was looking for it right now: https://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#PROG13

Comment: If you call the "leaky" function twice, does it leak more than 416 bytes in 6 blocks?

Comment: @opalenzuela: you might want to make an answer out of that link.

Comment: @nmichaels The author did refer to that link himself, but I believe the article about the security breach (that I didn't find yet) would be more selfexplanatory.

Comment: @rralf: Could you post a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FAQ of OpenSSL answers the question (Thanks to @opalenzuela):

> In most cases the cause of an apparent memory leak is an OpenSSL
>   internal table that is allocated when an application starts up. Since
>   such tables do not grow in size over time they are harmless.

Having a deeper look into OpenSSL's source shows:

```
/* Release all "ex_data" state to prevent memory leaks. This can't be made
 * thread-safe without overhauling a lot of stuff, and shouldn't really be
 * called under potential race-conditions anyway (it's for program shutdown
 * after all). */
void CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data(void)
    {
    IMPL_CHECK
    EX_IMPL(cleanup)();
    }
```

Comment: They are *not* harmless in all cases. As OpenSSL is loaded and unloaded in environments like Java and .Net, the leaked memory grows unbounded.