# Memory leak in OpenSSL?

Tags: c, openssl

I use the following code to check a signature. For simplicity public key, message and signature are initialized in `main`.

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

int main(){
    const unsigned char key[] = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
                "MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBALulMfYFyX1kSm7oUxZyCWWhrBBcWrRA\n"
                "V7LSz1PzMPxoxG3KS8H7PRKFkIk42yM8/vhobmcCmj7UM5572wWch50CAwEAAQ==\n"
                "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
    unsigned int key_len = sizeof(key);

    const unsigned char data[] = {0x6d,0x65,0x73,0x65,0x0a};
    unsigned int data_len = sizeof(data);

    const unsigned char sig[] = {0xa9,0x29,0x81,0x07,0x8c,0xeb,0xf0,0x1b,0x2a,0x31,0xe5,0x60,0x94,0x8a,0x47,0x94,0x3a,0x8f,0x6b,
                0x4e,0x85,0xb9,0xe7,0xe5,0x4a,0x6c,0x56,0x46,0xd1,0x80,0x15,0x57,0xce,0xcb,0x0a,0x3a,0x67,0x15,0xed,
                0x68,0x03,0x58,0x99,0xa4,0x73,0x61,0xe3,0x30,0x85,0xff,0x89,0x7e,0x32,0xef,0x16,0xec,0x23,0x7f,0x14,
                0xde,0xbf,0x53,0xe0,0x3a};
    unsigned int sig_len = sizeof(sig);


    EVP_PKEY* evp_pubkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
        RSA* rsa_pubkey = NULL;
    EVP_MD_CTX ctx;

    BIO* bufio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)key, key_len);
    if(bufio == NULL){  
        fprintf(stderr, "BIO not created.\n");
        EVP_PKEY_free(evp_pubkey);
        BIO_free(bufio);
        return 3;
    }

    evp_pubkey = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(bufio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(evp_pubkey == NULL){ 
        fprintf(stderr, "evp_pubkey not created.\n");
        EVP_PKEY_free(evp_pubkey);
        BIO_free(bufio);
        return 4;
    }

    EVP_MD_CTX_init(&ctx);  

    if (!EVP_VerifyInit(&ctx, EVP_sha256())) {
            fprintf(stderr, "EVP_SignInit: failed.\n");
            EVP_PKEY_free(evp_pubkey);
            BIO_free(bufio);
            return 5;
        }

        if (!EVP_VerifyUpdate(&ctx, data, data_len)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "EVP_SignUpdate: failed.\n");
                EVP_PKEY_free(evp_pubkey);
                BIO_free(bufio);
                return 6;
        }

        if (!EVP_VerifyFinal(&ctx, sig, sig_len, evp_pubkey)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "EVP_VerifyFinal: failed.\n");
            EVP_PKEY_free(evp_pubkey);
            BIO_free(bufio);
            return 7;
        }

        EVP_PKEY_free(evp_pubkey);
        BIO_free(bufio);

        return 0;
}
```

After compiling with `gcc evp.c -lssl -lcrypto` and running `valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full ./a.out` on it I get some memory leaks:

```
==7492== 56 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 9 of 12
==7492==    at 0x4C2BBCF: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7492==    by 0x4E9AD77: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==7492==    by 0x4F5D459: EVP_PKEY_new (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==7492==    by 0x400C4C: main (in a.out)
==7492== 
==7492== 120 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 10 of 12
==7492==    at 0x4C2BBCF: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7492==    by 0x4E9AD77: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==7492==    by 0x4F55678: EVP_DigestInit_ex (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==7492==    by 0x400D6A: main (in a.out)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Don't repeat yourself!!! Use `goto` or a function to handle errors. Also, 1. OpenSSL is not very *valgrind* friendly. 2. Are you using the `sizeof` operator intentionally like that, are you aware of the `nul` byte that is included in the length when you use the `sizeof`?

Comment: Possibly related: [OpenSSL *possible* memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21532371), [OpenSSL::SSL_library_init() memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11759725), [How to properly uninitialize OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29845527), [Memory leak in OpenSSL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34794272).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What @[iharob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983495/iharob) wrote in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34794364/1983495) and,
2. You used `EVP_MD_CTX_init()` but did not free the data it allocated using  `EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&ctx)` or - depending on your openssl version - `EVP_MD_CTX_free(&ctx)`.

   And if you compile with debug info (using -g in gcc/clang) *valgrind* would show you the source code lines responsible for the leaks.
3. You could also use `EVP_MD_CTX_create()` instead of using a static `EVP_MD_CTX`.

Here is the updated code:

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

int main() {
    const unsigned char key[] =
            "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
            "MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBALulMfYFyX1kSm7oUxZyCWWhrBBcWrRA\n"
            "V7LSz1PzMPxoxG3KS8H7PRKFkIk42yM8/vhobmcCmj7UM5572wWch50CAwEAAQ==\n"
            "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
    unsigned int key_len = sizeof(key) - 1;

    const unsigned char data[] = { 0x6d,0x65,0x73,0x65,0x0a };
    unsigned int data_len = sizeof(data);

    const unsigned char sig[] = {
            0xa9,0x29,0x81,0x07,0x8c,0xeb,0xf0,0x1b,0x2a,0x31,0xe5,0x60,
            0x94,0x8a,0x47,0x94,0x3a,0x8f,0x6b,0x4e,0x85,0xb8,0xe7,0xe5,
            0x4a,0x6c,0x56,0x46,0xd1,0x80,0x15,0x57,0xce,0xcb,0x0a,0x3a,
            0x67,0x15,0xed,0x68,0x03,0x58,0x99,0xa4,0x73,0x61,0xe3,0x30,
            0x85,0xff,0x89,0x7e,0x32,0xef,0x16,0xec,0x23,0x7f,0x14,0xde,
            0xbf,0x53,0xe0,0x3a
    };
    unsigned int sig_len = sizeof(sig);

    int ret = 0;

    EVP_PKEY* evp_pubkey = NULL;
    RSA* rsa_pubkey = NULL;
    EVP_MD_CTX* evp_ctx;
    BIO* bufio = NULL;

    if (!(bufio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)key, key_len))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "BIO not created.\n");
            ret = 1;
            goto out;
    }

    if (!(evp_pubkey = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(bufio, NULL, NULL, NULL))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "evp_pubkey not created.\n");
            ret = 2;
            goto out;
    }

    if (!(evp_ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create())) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ctx not created.\n");
            ret = 3;
            goto out;
    }

    if (!EVP_VerifyInit(evp_ctx, EVP_sha256())) {
            fprintf(stderr, "EVP_SignInit: failed.\n");
            ret = 4;
            goto out;
    }

    if (!EVP_VerifyUpdate(evp_ctx, data, data_len)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "EVP_SignUpdate: failed.\n");
            ret = 5;
            goto out;
    }

    if (!EVP_VerifyFinal(evp_ctx, sig, sig_len, evp_pubkey)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "EVP_VerifyFinal: failed.\n");
            ret = 6;
            goto out;
    }

out:
    if (evp_ctx)
            EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(evp_ctx);

    if (evp_pubkey)
            EVP_PKEY_free(evp_pubkey);

    if (bufio)
            BIO_free(bufio);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are overwriting the pointer here

```
evp_pubkey = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(bufio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

so the reference to the pointer returned by `EVP_PKEY_new()` the first time is lost and you can't free it anymore.