# Memory leak Using OpenSSL APIs

Tags: c, openssl

I am running a DTLS Server which handles more than 500 connections, every time some connections are closed I see memory utilization increasing.

I wonder there is a memory leak from my below approach of `Initialize_Sever_Context()`, `create_connexion()` and `close_connexion()`. The exact code is too big to create actual scenario, so I just outlined the step.

Pls let me know if any extra information is required?

I am using OpenSSL version 1.1.1k on Linux.

```
//connect_info structure user defined
{
 void* sll;
 void* bio;
 ....
}array_of_connections

*connect_info = &array_of_connections;
// global
SSL_CTX* server_ctx;

Initialize_Sever_Context()
{
    // server_ctx is global 
    server_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(DTLS_server_method());
    X509_VERIFY_PARAM *local_vpm = X509_VERIFY_PARAM_new()

    //setting verify flags, cookie flags and cypher lists etc..
    //....
    SSL_CTX_set1_param(server_ctx, local_vpm);
}

create_connexion(connect_info)
{
    // server_ctx is global
    ssl = SSL_new(server_ctx);
    
    bio = BIO_new_dgram(handler, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    ..
    ..
    SSL_set_bio(ssl, bio, bio);
    
    connect_info->ssl = ssl;
    connect_info->bio = bio;

}

handle_closed_connexions()
{
    for(conn = 1; conn<MAX_CONN;conn++)
    {
        close_connexion(connect_info[conn]);
    }
}

close_connexion(connect_info)
{
    // store prev ssl objects
    SLL *local_ssl = connect_info -> ssl;
    
    // make setup ready for the next connexions
    // and start listening
    create_connexion(connect_info)

    // free the previous closed connections
    SSL_free(local_ssl);
}
```

Inside `SSL_free()` we have `BIO_free_all(s->rbio)`, `BIO_free_all(s->rbio)` and `BIO_CTX_free(s->ctx)` and finally `OPENSSL_free(s)`.

As far as I understand when we do `SSL_free()`, all the members (pointers) inside the SSL object are freed.
But inside OpenSSL non of the pointers are set to `NULL` after `free()`, so I expect the application to crash.

But my application is working even after the pointers are freed.

Why does not OpenSSL set the pointers to `NULL` after they are freed or can I assume that my application is Safe with the above approach?

I have checked posts
[memory leak in openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794272/memory-leak-in-openssl) and
[how to properly uninitialize openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845527/how-to-properly-uninitialize-openssl) and others, but none of them satisfy my requirements, so I am asking a new question.

Comment: Fyi, your leaking your param object. `X509_VERIFY_PARAM *local_vpm = X509_VERIFY_PARAM_new()` will create a new param object with a reference count of 1. `SSL_CTX_set1_param(server_ctx, local_vpm);` will add the parameter to the context *and* increment the reference count by 1 (so now it's 2). Fyi, the `set1` functions bump the reference count of the intended object; `set0` does not (e.g. it assumes ownership takeover).

Comment: @WhozCraig, I don't see `set0` functions in OpenSSL code, we have `get0` functions.., could you pls point me at the full function name

Comment: Short version: once you configure your param object and attach it to the context, free it . Long version: Some api's don't have one or the other. Turns out there aren't any `0` functions for setting SSL_CTX parameters. You need to set the parameter object, then free it locally. the reference count should retain it in single-ownership within the context (and cleaned up when *that* is cleaned up). An example of configuration can be seen at the [code snippet  here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_flags.html) on the OpenSSL site (scroll near the bottom).

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig, that is a good suggestion and that is taken care, but unfortunately `Initialize_Sever_Context()` happens only once during the init, but in my case i believe `close_connexion` and `create_connexion` are causing more memory leak.., is the apporach i followed `handle_closed_connexions()` ==> `close_connexion` ==>`create_connexion` is right approach, can we have any better approach.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does not OpenSSL set the pointers to NULL after they are freed or Can i assume that my application is Safe with the above approach?

99.99% of the time, the pointers aren't going to be accessed again, so setting them to `NULL` serves no purpose. If you do happen to need them set to `NULL`, then you can set them to `NULL`.

Comment: Eventhough the pointers are not going to accessed again is it not a good coding practice to set them to `NULL`, to avoid accidental usage of same pointers? In case of OpenSSL when i call `SSL_free(s)`, i need to track the definition of `SSL_free` to find out what other objects its freeing, since its internal pointers are `free`d accessing any pointers inside `SSL` object with out allocating new memory again is wrong , but i dont see any abnormal behavior with my code.(since `server_ctx` is `free`d through `SSL_free` and i am using it again with out allocation new memory).

Comment: @Chandra No, that's actually a terrible coding practice for several reasons. Two key reasons: 1) The usual good coding practice is not to use the pointer again, so setting the value of a variable that your coding practice says not to check serves no purpose.  2) It can't provide "belt and suspenders" protection because it's perfectly normal and reasonable to have more than one pointer to the same allocated block and pointers to the middle of allocated blocks. Do you tediously write pointless code to `NULL` them all at the free point?